# Multiple questions about notation in a specific Baroque song

Tags: discussion

I want to arrange a particular 4-part Baroque song from a 1624 publication facsimile, and the notation has a number of facets I've never seen before.

Should I create a single post with all my questions about this one facsimile, or a set of micro-questions, one on each detail?

Comment: Actually, thank you for asking. Most users just barge on in with a multi-part question and then get upset when we ask them to break them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, it makes sense to split up many questions into multiple question posts. It helps future visitors find their answers faster if they have the same question. This makes sense especially if you are asking about different aspects of the notation that are orthogonal to each other.

This does not mean *every* question needs a separate post. For example if you are asking about symbol X,  one question containing the following is fine:

- What is X symbol?
- What does X convey notation wise?
- How do I convey X on instrument Y?

As you can see, all these question pertain to one symbol so it makes sense to keep them together.